# How to convert memoryview to bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I convert a Python memoryview to bytes?

For example:

```
>>> convert(memoryview(b"test"))
b"test"
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Python's memoryview has a [`tobytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview.tobytes) method that allows you to do just that. You're also able to call `bytes()` on the object.

Keep in mind that converting a memoryview object to bytes copies the data, and you're able to use memoryview in most places either way. I wouldn't suggest you to convert.

Comment: thanks! cryptography doesn't accept memoryview objects

Comment: Well then, send a patch to cryptography ;-)

Comment: Saying "you're able to use memoryview in most places either way" is not realy true - you can't do any operation on memoryview (like strip, find, ..) and in most cases I have to convert even if I don't want to.

Comment: @Jan you can use them in most places. Why are you stripping a bytes object?

Comment: @Jan Bytes are not meant to hold text lines, you're not really supposed to process whitespaces on the bytes object as you ignore the character encoding. The case of ASCII bytes, while prevalent, is quite unique and should be treated as so. Remember - processing strings is the job of str. Copying should be and can be avoided in most cases.

Comment: @Jan my friend, GStreamer is off topic. You realize your example is very specific to a library that broke backwards compatibility. Not everything is utf-8. Windows uses mainly utf-16, and  attempting to `.strip()` a utf-16 byte sequence can blow up your program. If you wish to do any sort of text processing on a byte sequence, you should count on the specific case of utf-8, and moreover I wouldn't use bytes anyway, but a bytearray. If you convert it to bytes in your case you're slowing down your code considerably, and taking twice the memory.

Comment: @jan And yes, there is such a thing as meant to hold. You wouldn't use strings to hold integers and you wouldn't use a byte sequence to hold a dictionary. Dictionaries, integers and text can be represented as bytes, but I prefer the dict type as it's meant for it, don't wish to reinvent addition operations on bytes, and don't wish to change all my code once a new encoding is introduced. Saying that GStreamer on Debian 11 doesn't work well, and everything is bytes are two sentences that completely miss the point, and are off topic.

Comment: @Bharel - I'm really sorry for the whole debate, It's hugely offtopic and I was just reacting because I felt like you were attacking me because I used bytes (which is/was beyound my control) so I felt I have to explain myself, but that serves no point. I propose I'll delete my comments and you can delete your reactions to me.

Comment: @Bharel - I'm deleting my off-topic comments, if you want to discuss it with me - i made a chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/134045/removing-clarification-of-off-topic-comments-on-memoryview-bytes?tab=general